# why does the cell in the jupyter notebook shows executing when it has already generated the output?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using JupyterLab in dataproc cluster. I have noticed a couple of times that when i execute a cell in Jupyter, it returns the output but still shows the executing symbol(*). What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: What Dataproc image version do you use and how do you create JupyterLab notebook?

Comment: 1.4 ubuntu , by enabling optional component

Comment: Is it consistently reproducible for you, or happened only once? What notebook kernel do you use?

Comment: happened couple of times, i use Python kernel

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but it works for me. Maybe it happens when you are executing some specific command? Is this the case, or it happens for different commands/statements execution? Also, does cell re-execution fixes its status?

Comment: It usually happens when i use ```.show()```

Comment: Did you install any additional extension and/or libraries in your Jupyter?